# No Module Named cx_Oracle

Tags: python, batch-file, cx-oracle

I created and execute a python script using PyCharm with Cx_Oracle module and it is working (able to select from an oracle table) but when I tried to use .bat file to execute the same python script, error below is showing.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'

Note that the same script is working using PyCharm but not error when using .bat

bat script:

```
python C:\Users\rtorreverde\PycharmProjects\TableToBusinessTerm\testargv.py
pause
```

.py absolute path:

```
C:\Users\rtorreverde\PycharmProjects\TableToBusinessTerm\testargv.py
```

error message:

[image: Error message]

Comment: Likely the script and PyCharm are pointing to different Python environments.

Comment: OK - so the batch *was* there. I didn't see it because it hadn't been formatted. From the error message, it would seem that `cx_oracle` doesn't exist in `...businessterm\kpir_glossarydescription` - I'd guess it is in `....businessterm`. I'd suggest you execute `pushd "c:\Users\rtorreverde\PycharmProjects\TableToBusinessTerm` before the `python...` line. Since the batch terminates after the `python...` command, a matching `popd` is probably redundant.